# How can I read the Mac OSX's Double click duration programmatically?

Tags: macos, operating-system, mouseevent

I need to read and use the operating systems double click duration setting.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSTimeInterval doubleClickInterval = [NSEvent doubleClickInterval];
```